# How to recompile macport with additional ./configure flag?

Tags: macports

I have a py27-tkinter macport installed and it seems that it is compiled without "--enable-threads" flag that makes it unusable. It is any easy way without hand modification of portfile to recompile this port with addition `./configure` flag? Brief internet search shows `configure.args`, but this command:

```
sudo port upgrade --force py27-tkinter configure.args="--enable-threads"
```

Changes nothing. Is it something i'm doing wrong or manual portfile modification is the only way?

Comment: dont you want `--disable-threads` or something along those lines?

Comment: Sorry, i can't understand your comment :(. The correct additional command for `./configure` script is `--enable-threads`. I don't know anything about `--disable-threads`, they are disabled by default AFAIK.

Comment: Ahh and you want them enabled? Because your question said its already compiled with that flag... you might ant to edit that: `seems that it is compiled with "--enable-threads" flag that makes it unusable` shoudl be "*seems that it is compiled **without** "--enable-threads" flag that makes it unusable*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: need to reinstall `tcl` macport with `+threads` variant.